# how to randomly select a neighbor patch that has a higher elevation in netlogo

Tags: random, patch, netlogo, elevation

how to randomly select among all the neighbour patches that are higher instead of the highest neighbour patch? 
I was thinking to remove (if elevation >= [elevation] of max-one-of neighbors [elevation] [stop])
and place "[stop]" in [move-to-one-of neighbors [stop]]

```
to move ; a turtle procedure

if elevation >= [elevation] of max-one-of neighbors [elevation] [stop]


ifelse random-float 1 < q
[uphill elevation]
[move-to one-of neighbors]

end
```

Comment: First you want to define how many higher patches you want to measure, you can choose amongst all 8 and just choose one randomly or you can choose the highest. 

On the other hand, you could think of having some kind of treshold that would define when a patch is a candidate to being chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`one-of` randomly selects an agent from the agentset and `with` creates an agentset of those agents satisfying the condition. You will also need to test that there is at least one location to go to. The selection would look like this (with threshold condition to be determined):

```
to move-up ; a turtle procedure
  let candidates neighbors with [elevation >= <thresholdhold condition> ]
  if any? candidates [ move-to one-of candidates]
end
```

If you are instead wanting to choose amongst the higher neighbours regardless of whether they are higher than some threshold, you want `max-n-of`. Looks like this to choose one of the 3 highest:

```
to move-up
  move-to one-of max-n-of 3 neighbors [elevation]
end
```

Comment: what is a thresholdhold condition? is it elevation?

Comment: It might be something like elevation > 20. Your question was unclear as to whether you wanted to select from those that were higher than some number (or threshold) and those that were the higher within the neighbors group. What do you want to happen when the turtle is at the top of their local hill?

Answer (score 1):

```
; The butterfly move procedure in turtle context
to move ; a turtle procedure
  if elevation >= [elevation] of max-one-of neighbors [elevation] [stop]
  ; Decide whether to move uphill deterministically with probability q
  ifelse random-float 1 < q
   [ uphill elevation ] ; move uphill
   [ move-to one-of neighbors ] ; otherwise move randomly
   set patches-visited patches-visited + 1
end
```