# How To Move Turtles To Highest Random Neighbour Patches

Tags: random, move, netlogo, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get the turtles to randomly select among all the neighbour patches that are higher. My code gets the turtle to move to the highest patch but I want it to do this randomly.

my code:

```
to move
  if elevation >= [elevation] of max-one-of neighbors[elevation]
  [stop]

  ifelse random-float 1 < q
    [ uphill elevation ]                
    [ move-to one-of neighbors]       

  set patches-visited patches-visited + 1

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to randomly select a neighbor patch that has a higher elevation in netlogo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081116/how-to-randomly-select-a-neighbor-patch-that-has-a-higher-elevation-in-netlogo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in one line

```
move-to one-of neighbors with [elevation > [elevation] of myself]]
```

in your code it would like this

```
to move
   if elevation < [elevation] of max-one-of neighbors[elevation]
   [  
   move-to one-of neighbors with [elevation > [elevation] of myself]]
   set patches-visited patches-visited + 1
   ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but where about's in my code should I paste that?

Comment: I wrote a cleaner version of your procedure in the answer